# Problem in using getpass with psycog for password management

Tags: python, python-3.5, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3, getpass

My goal is to use getpass to hide the entry of my password when I connect to a postgresql database via python3.
I use python3 on jyputer notebook.

This work well :

```
connect = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_toto' user='dad' host='xx.xx.xxx.x' port='5432' password='123456'")
cur = connect.cursor()
```

But when I try to enter the password with a separate variable, it does not work anymore :

```
pw = getpass.getpass() 
####Python ask me to tape password and i tape the same '123456'
```

To verify :

```
'123456'

connect=psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_toto' user='dad' host='xx.xx.xxx.x' port='5432' password=pw")
cur=connect.cursor()
```

---

```
" OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "
```

[received error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIgcy.png)

Thanks you for your help

Comment: You're passing the password as `pw`, not `123456`, as I expect that you intended.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is passing a string to the `connect` function. This string has the value of `"dbname='db_toto' user='dad' host='xx.xx.xxx.x' port='5432' password=pw"`. The `psycopg2` module has no way of knowing what `pw` is. I suspect it will be converted to a string (`'pw'`), but I'm not sure.

Anyway, the correct approach would be to pass keyword arguments to the `connect` function like so:

```
connect = psycopg2.connect(dbname='db_toto' user='dad' host='xx.xx.xxx.x' port='5432' password=pw)
# Notice the lack of double-quotes in the arguments
```

This way, you will be passing the contents of the `pw` variable to the function, instead of the name `pw`.

It is possible to pass the contents of the `pw` variable in string form as well, like so:

```
connect = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_toto' user='dad' host='xx.xx.xxx.x' port='5432' password='{}'".format(pw))
```

The first form should be preferred.

Comment: The second form ( xxx.format(pw) ) worked well. The first send same error again. So i use the second. Thank you so much